# Filesystem owner changed by mistake

Tags: apt, dpkg, chown, debconf

I ran this command on my ubuntu 12.04 by mistake:

```
chown someuser / -R
```

On RHEL it would be fixed by this command:

```
rpm --setugids -a
```

Is there anyway to fix it in ubuntu server?

Comment: Please do not crosspost your question. http://serverfault.com/questions/457725/filesystem-owner-changed-by-mistake

Answer (score 1):

[There is not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42209/is-it-possible-to-reset-all-folder-permissions) an straight forward way to do it, as far as I know. This answer can probaly help you a bit: https://superuser.com/questions/132891/how-to-reset-folder-permissions-to-their-default-in-ubuntu-9-10